I got permission error while create-expo-app
I am trying to get started with my first expo project,
so run this command on my terminal at VScode on my window
npx create-expo-app ./
but I got this error message
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\earth\.expo'
node:internal/bootstrap/node:123
        validateInteger(value, 'code');
        ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('EPERM')
    at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:123:9)
    at process.exit (node:internal/process/per_thread:180:24)
    at C:\Users\earth\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\a712338f43e79bae\node_modules\create-expo-app\build\index.js:95:736
    at <anonymous>
    at async run (C:\Users\earth\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\a712338f43e79bae\node_modules\create-expo-app\build\index.js:95:704) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v20.18.0
Is there any way to fix this?

Change to . instead of ./, it is not windows path.

I have change to . but its still got the same error

Can you check your task manager for existing tasks connected to expo/node?

Plus - try to close vscode and run from shell in the right folder. Can you share the installation steps?
